# Выбрать текст по ограничителям

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим имеется документ такого содержания:

```
Ненужный текст

//->strat
   Любой текст и символы номер 1
//->end

Ненужный текст

//->strat
   Любой текст и символы номер 2
//->end

Ненужный текст
```

Как правильно составить регулярное выражение для JS, что бы после поиска выходной массив был плана

```
[0] => 'Любой текст и символы номер 1'
[1] => 'Любой текст и символы номер 2'
```

То есть что бы выбирались участки текста только между "открывающими"и "закрывающими" ключами?

Предположил такое выражение [`/\/\/->start([\s\S]*)\/\/->end/`](https://regex101.com/r/DFP0Ik/3)(кликабельно), но понятное дело оно работает не так как нужно. Предполагаю, что необходимо как-то ограничить фрагмент с `[\s\S]`, но как именно понять не могу.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Скобки круглые ставите не вокруг всего выражения, а вокруг `[\s\S]*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен [ленивый поиск](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy#%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC)
`/\/\/->start([\s\S]*?)\/\/->end/g`

Получить искомый массив в JS можно так:

```
var re = /\/\/->start([\s\S]*?)\/\/->end/g;
var str = '<ваш текст>';
var m;
var a = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    a.push(m[1]);    
}
```